# Make a concatenate strings recognize as a declared variable in java

Tags: java, string, variables

```
public class Assignment1 {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String e1 = "apple"; String e2 = "mango";
        String e3 = "banana"; String e4 = "cherry"; String fruit;
        int num = 1;
        while (num <= 4){
            fruit = "e" + num;
            System.out.println(fruit);
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

I made a sample code of what I will doing, I expect that the code result will be output as

```
apple
mango
banana
cherry
```

but what I got is:

```
e1
e2
e3
e4
```

Can you please help me to make the concatenated strings recognize as a string variable that I supposedly declared?

Comment: You should use an array instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an array:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String[] e = {"apple", "mango", "banana", "cherry"};
    for (int num = 0; num < e.length; ++num) {
        System.out.println(e[num]);
    }
}
```

Another way to write the loop is

```
    for (String fruit : e) {
        System.out.println(fruit);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot "address" local variables by name (reflection can help you with member member variables, but not with locals).

You need an associative container for addressing items using a string name - for example, a `HashMap<String,String>`. Add pairs `{"e1", "apple"}, {"e2", "mango"}`, and so on to a `HashMap`, and then use `map.get(fruit)` to retrieve the value by key.

```
HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
map.put("e1", "apple");
map.put("e2", "mango");
...
int num = 1;
while (num <= 4){
    fruit = "e" + num;
    System.out.println(map.get(fruit));
    num++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't concatenate an Integer to a String and expect that e + "1" will evaluate the variable e1. You should put all the String variables inside an array and iterate

```
        String e1 = "Mango";
        String e2 = "Apple";
        String e3 = "Banana";
        String e4 = "Cherry";

        String[] fruits = {e1, e2, e3, e4};
        String allFruits = new String();

        for(String fruit : fruits){
            allFruits += " " + fruit;
        }

        System.out.println(allFruits);
```

Comment: You should never need to do `new String()`, you can use `""` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can also using an `enum`:

```
public enum Fruit {
   APPLE, MANGO, BANANA, CHERRY
}
```

Store it:

```
List<Fruit> fruits = new ArrayList<Fruit>();
fruits.add(Fruit.APPLE);
fruits.add(Fruit.MANGO);
fruits.add(Fruit.BANANA);
fruits.add(Fruit.CHERRY);
```

And iterate it:

```
for (Fruit fruit : fruits)
   System.out.println(fruit);
```

Answer (score -1):

@dasblinkenlight Good aproach. Only one detail, you have to declare variable fruit:

```
String fruit = "e" + num;
```